# error: conversion from ‘const char’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} requested

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I want to count letters in const string&, and save result in map.
But compiler throws an error:

> error: conversion from ‘const char’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} requested

My code:

```cpp
map<string, int>& MakeWordCounter (const string& word, map<string, int>& counter) {
    for (string i : word) {
        counter[i] = count(word.begin(), word.end(), i);
    }
}
```

Why this error is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The loop `for (string i : word)` loops over the *characters* in the string `word`. The variable `i` need to be a `char`.

Comment: Do you want to split the input string? What's your input and expected output?

Comment: My input is: "foobar_aaa", expected output is map {{"f", 1}, {"o", 2}, {"b", 1}, {"a", 4}, {"r", 1}, {"_", 1}}

Comment: `for (char i : word) {` or `for (auto i : word) {`.

Comment: There's also the problem of the function being declared to return something, but not actually returning anything.

Comment: Retired Ninja, thank you, problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dereferenced iterator of `word` has the type `char`, we can't convert it to string. And the function declaration can be more clear to directly return the map.

The key type here is char, we don't need to use a `string` type, its misleading and is a waste.

```cpp
std::map<char, size_t> MakeWordCounter(const std::string& word) {
  std::map<char, size_t> counts;
  for (auto ch : word) {
    counts[ch]++;
  }
  return counts;
}
```

Or we can use STL algorithm instead of loop:

```cpp
std::map<char, size_t> MakeWordCounter2(const std::string& word) {
  return std::accumulate(word.begin(), word.end(), std::map<char, size_t>{},
                         [](auto init, char cur) {
                           init[cur] += 1;
                           return init;
                         });
}
```

You may doubt the second version's performance, so I add the benchmark here, the two versions are generally the same.

https://quick-bench.com/q/OSzzp70rBSdlpivEMmMIj0aGJfU

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M7qxooqfx)